# 2 by 2 heatmap matrix visualization from grouped data

Tags: python, heatmap, display

I'm trying to create a 2 by 2 heatmap matrix, but the matrix looks like below and I would like to display the number of 'count' on each matrix. Thank you all for your help in advance!

[image]

my code is

```
pip.install heatmapz
from heatmap import heatmap, corrplot

    values = [
    ['Female','Female',190],
    ['Female','Male',131]],
    ['Female','Female',118]],
    ['Female','Female',327]]
]
df: pd.Dataframe = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = [ 'Gender_out','Gender_in','Count']

 heatmap(
        x= df['Gender_out'], 
        y= df['Gender_in'],
        color = df['Count'])
```

Comment: First of all, the data is not in two-dimensional format. Also, you don't have a sector_group defined. Isn't this a df? `values = [['Female','Male',190],['Male','Female',131],['Female','Female',118],['Male','Male',327]]`

Comment: You're right! I edited my question! Thanks!

Comment: If you also modify the data, you will see the graph in the image in the question.

Comment: I used seaborn instead! it worked great. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I use seaborn, if you can change the module try it.

```
values = [
        ['Female','Female',190],
        ['Female','Male',131],
        ['Female','Female',118],
        ['Female','Female',327],
        ['Male','Female',0]
        ]
df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = [ 'Gender_out','Gender_in','Count'])

A = pd.crosstab(df["Gender_out"], df["Gender_in"], df["Count"], aggfunc=sum)

import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
XY = np.random.normal(0, 20, (10,10))
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = sns.heatmap(A, annot=True, fmt="f")
```

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Comment: I'm trying to use seaborn heatmap instead of heatmpaz. I feel like I can fix this! Thanks!

Comment: I have added some example that may be useful (and to avoid my post deletion). I have modified a bit your data, but I think the example will be enough for you to take it from here.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example, Marcello! I was able to create the matrix I wanted! Thanks agian!